# I want to know If I can create a report or alert on Bulk API Jobs whenever a Job has Failed

Tags: bulk-api, custom-report-type, scheduled-job

I want to know If I can create a report or alert on Bulk API Jobs such that  whenever a Job has Failed. If we can create a VF page then on which standard controller I can start with.

Comment: Something like this may be something you're looking for, creating a new object and recording an error if there is a failure  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/112621/which-of-these-error-handling-patterns-is-more-efficient/112677#112677, you would be able to create a vf page off this object